# Can't reach server 404 error

Tags: java, android

My app connects to a server to to do several things. Everything was working ok, and somehow, probably i deleted something (server or client side), and i get the following message in LogCat when i try to Login(by this way i connect to the server):

```
02-13 03:49:10.341: E/JSON(381): 404 Not Found

The requested URL /android_login_api/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Foundnerror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Though this message appears, i haven't changed the URL i was using to connect so far to the server, and more awkwardly, i can connect to the server, with FTP access by using the same configuration. Any ideas??

Comment: Have you checked your server's url in browser?

Comment: also consider logging the full URL that you have right before you make the request, perhaps some portion of it got messed up.

Comment: Well the app uses a specific URL which connects to the server, this hasn't changed at all.

Comment: What is `E/JSON(381)`? Looks like a line number. Do you have code that fails to 404 if an error is encountered?

Comment: if i m not mistaking 381 is the PID (process id). 404 is what is being returned to the app.It's supposed to appear when a connection could not be established to server, because the server is  not found.The whole message: 02-13 03:49:10.341: E/JSON(381): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">n<html><head>n<title>404 Not Found</title>n</head><body>n<h1>Not Found</h1>n<p>The requested URL /android_login_api/ was not found on this server.</p>n<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Foundnerror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>n</body></html>

Comment: maybe there is no url or you send the wrong data url to the server